# How can I change my desktop background every time I log in?

Tags: macos, desktop

I want to download all of the background images from here: http://www.surfermag.com/wallpapers/

And have a new one load up every time I log into my Mac. What's the easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you select the folder where your custom background images are in the left section, then you just select `Change picture:` and choose `When logging in` in the dropdown.

[image]